# Multiple Get Requests for One Action

Tags: javascript, django, get, bootstrap-modal

I currently have a CRUD reminder app and has a context menu with options such as edit, delete, etc. Buttons on the context menu are updated based on the reminders id, and ids are passed to a [bootstrap modal form](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms).

```
function toggleMenuOn(e) {
    if ( menuState !== 1 ) {
      menuState = 1;
      menu.classList.add( contextMenuActive );
    }

    let reminder_id = e.target.id
    let context_btn1 = document.getElementById("context_menu_btn1");
    let reminder_pk = reminder_id.replace("reminder", "");
    let reminder_url = "{% url 'update-reminder' 0 %}".replace(/0/, reminder_pk) 
    context_btn1.className = "update-reminder context-menu__link btn btn-light";
    context_btn1.setAttribute('data-id', reminder_url);
    $("#context_menu_btn1").modalForm({formURL: reminder_url});
  }
```

However, when I looked in the command line, I saw many GET requests for one button click:

```
[22/Dec/2019 17:50:01] "GET /update_reminder/8/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4650
[22/Dec/2019 17:50:01] "GET /update_reminder/4/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4681
[22/Dec/2019 17:50:01] "GET /update_reminder/8/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4650
[22/Dec/2019 17:50:01] "GET /update_reminder/4/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4681
```

The interesting thing is, when the page is first loaded and I click edit on a reminder, one GET request appears. But when I click it another time, 2 GET requests appear, with alternating links, as shown above. On the third edit click 3 GET requests show up. I had a look in the network tab in inspect element and shows the same. This is a problem as it slows down the page and sometimes returns the incorrect form url. I am quite lost on how and why it is happening, as modalForm is only called once.

Comment: You should execute `GET` requests only on button click, you can bind events to the buttons and `onclick` execute the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new `modalForm` each time you toggle the menu, since you put its declaration in `toggleMenuOn`. Instead, you should declare it once (when the application loads), see [their README](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms#how-it-works):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".create-book").modalForm({
        formURL: "{% url 'create_book' %}"
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I actually had that in the first place, but the modal wouldn't update. It would only display the update modal for the first reminder clicked. For example, if I click edit reminder1, then try to edit reminder2, it would only display update reminder1.